# how can i user razor syntax in asp.net project not mvc

Tags: asp.net, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we use Razor syntax in ASP.NET Webforms (*.aspx pages)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264852/can-we-use-razor-syntax-in-asp-net-webforms-aspx-pages)

is it possible to use razor syntax in asp.net project web form and cshtml file

> @{
>
> var greeting = "Welcome to our site!";
>
> ```
> }
> ```

Comment: no, razor is only in mvc views, i think nothing has changed since this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5264852/944681) was asked..

Comment: ASP.NET Helpers component dosent work for  none mvc project ?

Comment: An explanation of what is and is not possible can be found here http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx additional info can be found here too http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/162/Using-Web-Pages-Helpers-in-ASP.NET-Web-Forms