# Can I use razor engine in existing Asp.net web forms application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently i use <% %> tags in web forms view engine to generate dynamic content; however it has some limitations, while MVC razor engine has a very powerful syntax and does not have web forms view engine.

Can i use razor view engine in existing Asp.net web forms application?

Comment: Same Q & A here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264852/can-we-use-razor-syntax-in-asp-net-webforms-aspx-pages

Answer (score 0):

you can use razor engine, only add razor package at your project, i working with VS 2012, and work, use this

Before create some directory to put your templates, for example "Views"

```
string viewPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Views/yourTemplate.cshtml");
var teamplate = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(viewPath);
string view = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(teamplate, model);
```

model is any class with properties (setter and getter);

In your cshtml file  put this sentence at the top

```
@{

    Layout = null;
}
```