# could not run ASP.net code in localhost

Tags: asp.net, function

I had enabled the IIS features
and follow the tutorials to build my 1st ASP.NET page
but when I run the code, this problem occer

[image]

but it suppose to display current time instead of @DateTime.now()
did I missed out something?

Comment: also please remove asp-classic from tags

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use w3schools. [Their tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_razor.asp) lacks lots of explanation, especially on how to set things up. You [cannot use Razor in aspx pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264852/can-we-use-razor-syntax-in-asp-net-webforms-aspx-pages). Are you sure you want to learn ASP.NET Web Pages? Try [the official site](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) or take a look at [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Comment: ASP.NET must use RAZOR syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename the file to `.cshtml` in order to let it be rendered as Web Page with the Razor engine. See [Intro to ASP.NET Web Programming Razor Syntax : The Official Microsoft ASP.NET Site](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29).