# How to Use Razor Layout in ASP .NET Web Form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, layout, razor, webforms

I am using ASP.Net Web form in my MVC 5 application.

I want to use my Razor view layout in the ASP.Net web form. How can i do that?

Comment: Razor view layout?... did you mean Bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: Similar question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264852/can-we-use-razor-syntax-in-asp-net-webforms-aspx-pages

Comment: "using a web form in an MVC application"? That's unlikely, as they're two very different application architectures. Further, what do you mean by "how to use Razor view layout" Razor is a syntax, not a view layout. Even if it were a view layout, "how to use it" is way too broad/unclear a question to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with **ASP.NET web application using VS 2013** and add a **MVC 5 View Page (Razor)** on right clicking the Project.

Answer (score 0):

you can't , because ASP.Net Mvc and ASP.Net web form using a different view engine, you should use Mvc View Master Page or Master Page

Comment: There is no option like MVC View Master Page

Comment: mvc5 removed ,you can only use Master Page

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right. If you mean the Template layout frmo ASP.NET MVC.. this is from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/). If you mean the Concept "Masterpage-Layout-Page" for Winform, you can create a Masterpage:

- Add -> New Item
- Web Forms Master Page
- Design and add `ContentPlaceHolder` for your Content..
- Add -> New Item
- Web Form with Master Page
- Select your "Site".Master